# How do I make a callback to delete an instance of a class that exists in a another class?

Tags: c#

I making a program that simulates what happens in a Chat Application.
Here I have a class named Person(Client) and a class named Room(server), that contains Person instances in an List. I have figured out how a Person can receive a message, but when a Person can no longer receive, how can I make a callback in Room class and remove the instance of that Person from the Room?

```
public class Person
{
    readonly IConnection connection;
    string remainingMessage = "";

    public Person(IConnection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public Message Read()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
        string text = remainingMessage;

        while (true)
        {
            int position = text.IndexOf('$');
            if (position != -1)
            {
                remainingMessage = text.Substring(position + 1);
                return new Message(text.Substring(0, position));
            }
            int read = connection.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (read == 0)
            {
            // callback in Room to remove this person
            }
            text += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}

public class Room
{
    List<Person> personsList = new List<Person>();
    readonly IConnection connection;

    public Room(IConnection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        personsList.Add(person);
    }

    public void Leave(Person person)
    {
        personsList.Remove(person);
    }
```

Comment: How did you add the person in the first place?

Comment: @vasily.sib: clearly this is a study case (well, I hope :-) ). When learning, it is often a good thing to use concrete, easy to grasp examples.

Comment: @Stefan sure, but I think that if he had a concrete, easy to grasp example - there will be no question on SO. BTW, here is [concrete, easy to grasp examples of SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples)

Comment: @vasily.sib _"SignalR"_ - Maybe he wants to use named pipes.  Maybe it is local host? Maybe there is no actual comms and its a simulation. He did say _"simulation"_ after all. Simply saying _"Why do you reinventing a wheel?"_ as a generalization is a trump card to end all future development of new open source projects.  And no one wants that.  MS made SignalR **and** _SourceSafe_.  I for one am glad for the existence of _Git_ and the decision to reinvent the wheel on that one

Comment: @MickyD I don't want to end all future development of new open source projects, but I'm sure there is no need in new chat app engine:\ But you are right - _"reinventing a wheel"_ is a exaggeration (and also looks a little rude, sorry about that) so I will remove my comment and leave here a link to [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction) and a request to show the code of `IConnection` as without it this question can't be answered.

Comment: That's fine thanks @vasily.sib.  Incidentally, I was going to cite SignalR as an open-source project but was surprised to learn it was MS. Hence my Git reference. lol. 
 Wishing you well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. implement a not responding event.
2. raise the event in Person class when Person can no longer receive.
3. subscribe event in Room class and delete that person from the list when the event raised.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing `Room` and `Person` have in common, is the `IConnection`, which receives, send and transports data.

So, your `IConnection` *could* be something like this:

```
//note, this is high level connection interface, with functional 
//it's often done by communicating Id's
public interface IConnection
{
    void ConnectPerson(int personId);
    void DisconnectPerson(int personId);

    //Sadegh Javanmard's suggested delegate handler:
    void OnNotResponding(int personId);
}
```

Since you have access to this interface on both "sides", you will be able to control and invoke functions. Do note this is a simplified representation of the real world and if you want to build an actual chat room, use SignalR as suggested by @vasily.sib

If you like to have a more formal design in place to handle this; have a look at the [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) and [observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or perhaps the [proxy](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-proxy) pattern.

*Note: this still is a simplified representation compared to e.g. the signalR library.*